# Any reason to keep assets logging in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I find the asset logging not quite useful during development and I'm thinking about using the `quiet_assets` gem to disable asset logging in production. Is that a good idea? Any reason why I should care about asset logging in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much logging you want is something you should decide. One may only need very basic logging information whereas someone else may need a very detailed logging.

Disabling assets logging in production is not bad, it won't hurt anything since it's just logs.

However it may come a time where you'll need those logs to debug assets not being served for example.

It's up to you.